# How to plot linear regression between two continous values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to implement a Machine-Learning algorithm to predict house prices in New-York-City.

Now, when I try to plot (using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html)) the relationship between two columns of my house-prices dataset: 'gross_sqft_thousands' (the gross area of the property in thousands of square feets) and the target-column which is the 'sale_price_millions', I get a weird plot like this one:

[image: gross_sqft_thousands vs sale_price_millions]

Code used to plot:

```
sns.regplot(x="sale_price_millions", y="gross_sqft_thousands", data=clean_df);
```

When I try to plot the number of commercial units (commercial_units column) versus the sale_price_millions, I get also a weird plot like this one:

[image]

These weird plots, although in the correlation matrix, the sale_price correlates very good with both variables (gross_sqft_thousands and commercial_units).

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to get great plot, with less points and a clear fitting like this plot:

[image: great plot with fewer points]

Here is a part of my dataset:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your housing price dataset is much larger than the `tips` dataset shown in that Seaborn example plot, so scatter plots made with default settings will be massively overcrowded.

The second plot looks "weird" because it plots a (practically) continuous variable, sales price, against an integer-valued variable, `total_units`.

The following solutions come to mind:

1. Downsample the dataset with something like `sns.regplot(x="sale_price_millions", y="gross_sqft_thousands", data=clean_df[::10])`. The `[::10]` part selects every 10th line from `clean_df`. You could also try `clean_df.sample(frac=0.1, random_state=12345)`, which randomly samples 10% of all rows 
   without replacement (using a random seed for reproducibility).
2. Reduce the alpha (opacity) and/or size of the scatterplot points with `sns.regplot(x="sale_price_millions", y="gross_sqft_thousands", data=clean_df, scatter_kws={"alpha": 0.1, "s": 1})`.
3. For plot 2, add a bit of "jitter" (random noise) to the y-axis variable with `sns.regplot(..., y_jitter=0.05)`.

For more, check out the Seaborn documentation on `regplot`: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html

Comment: Great to hear! I just added a third suggestion to make the second plot more readable: add `y_jitter=0.05` or some other small value to the arguments of `regplot`. Happy coding!

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! Helped! Would you mind looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56417430/how-to-get-legend-next-to-plot-in-seaborn